# Startup code in cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, browser

I am very very new in Cordova (a few weeks), and building an iOS app, and I am trying to implement a code which opens an external url in the default browser, Safari.  I am following a tutorial which says to "use the following as part of the startup code in your Cordova app":

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
$(document).on('click', 'a[target="_system"],a[target="_blank"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    window.open(url,"_system");
    });
//}
}, false);
```

How do I add this as a part of the startup code?  Would it be a script tag at the top of the page?  I tried that and got no luck.
Here is the link to the tutorial I am using: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jul/02/External-Links-in-Cordova-for-iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you showed should be included with script tag as you tried. After that you need to add link element in your HTML and click that. So your *index.html* would look something like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      $(document).on('click', 'a[target="_system"],a[target="_blank"]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = this.href;
        window.open(url,"_system");
      });
    }, false);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://google.com/" target="_system">Go to Google.com</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

What the script actually does is that it registers itself as event handler for *click* event so basically it is called every time some link with *target="_system"* or *target="_blank"* is clicked. When it is called, it first prevents any other event handlers for it from being executed (*e.preventDefault();*). After that it reads the URL for the link clicked and opens that with the external browser (*window.open(url, "_system");*).

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot to add the cordova script tag.